# ORDER BY query copying into tmp table

Tags: mysql, sql

My MYSQL Query :

```
select id, title, slug, price, image, cat
  from demo
 where main_cat = 1
 order by id desc
 limit 200000, 20
```

Explain Details :

```
select_type : SIMPLE
table : demo 
type :ref 
possible_keys :main_cat 
key :main_cat  
key_len:4  
ref :const 
rows :9050910 
Extra :Using where; Using filesort
```

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) says:

```
Temporary tables can be created under conditions such as these:

            If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause,or 
if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first 
table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.
```

..

My query contain only ORDER BY so Why goes to TMP Table ?

Comment: we don't know your table structure, we don't even have a complete query and result of explain so how do you expect us to help?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of the `explain`?

Comment: @peter explain output added now

Comment: @Puciek explain output added now

Comment: It doesn't show that it's using temporary table, unless I went blind :)

Comment: @Puciek Thnx for replay ...when excute this query I got this error :  error writing file '/tmp/MYTRRRDT' (Errcode:28)

Comment: You can use fantastic perror command http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/perror.html , but essentially you've ran out of space :)

Comment: @Puciek Can you give any suggestion for sortfile problem....my table size around 12GB and 9 millions records....so may be this is cause

Comment: Well, disk space is used for a lot more than just temptables, for example it will also be used for index searches. ANd if you want to play with 12gb of data, you need to clear up space on disk, that is all to it.

Comment: @Puciek each time copy into tmptables when every query fire OR just first time table copy into tmp table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what a standard error code means:

```
$ perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

So you don't have enough space on the filesystem where /tmp is located. It was probably writing to it fine for a while, but tried to write a result set that was too large.

Your EXPLAIN output does not show a temporary table. But it does show "Using filesort" which can also use disk space if your result set is large enough.

For example, if it has to sort 200000 rows to find the offset. :-)

Is your `image` column the actual image in a BLOB? That could explain the size of the result set.

Using LIMIT with a very large number for the offset isn't a good idea. MySQL has to generate the whole result set before it can do the offset.

It would be better to do offsets by *value* rather than by *position*.

```
select id, title, slug, price, image, cat
  from demo
 where main_cat = 1 and id < $lowest_id_from_previous_page
 order by id desc
 limit 20
```

Comment: all column in VARCHAR except id and price column...and id < $lowest_id_from_previous_page which not possible in my cases because  i have also use ORDER BY `bestseller' in many places...

Comment: Then configure `tmpdir` to a filesystem with more space.